# Could we define cardinal number on well-founded equality?

Tags: induction, cardinals

[Cardinal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) and [Ordinal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) are two concepts derived from human abilities on judging and comparing quantities, the two intuitive roots of [number sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sense).

For ordinal number we have axioms as below:

- O1: trichotomy, for any elements x and y, exactly one of these statements is true:

  - x < y
  - y < x
  - x = y
- O2: transitivity, for any elements x, y, z, if x < y and y < z, then x < z.
- O3: well-ordered, every nonempty subset has a least element, that is, it has an element x such that there is no other element y in the subset where y < x.

On the other hand, the definition of Cardinal number is a little bit complex. So let's just back to the Peano numbers.

- P1: 0 is a natural number.
- P2: axioms on equality

  - P2.1: for every natural number x, x = x. That is, equality is reflexive.
  - P2.2: for all natural numbers x and y, if x = y, then y = x. That is, equality is symmetric.
  - P2.3: for all natural numbers x, y and z, if x = y and y = z, then x = z. That is, equality is transitive.
  - P2.4: for all a and b, if b is a natural number and a = b, then a is also a natural number. That is, the natural numbers are closed under equality.
- P3: axioms on successor

  - P3.1: for every natural number n, S(n) is a natural number. That is, the natural numbers are closed under S.
  - P3.2: for all natural numbers m and n, m = n if and only if S(m) = S(n). That is, S is an injection.
  - P3.3: for every natural number n, S(n) = 0 is false. That is, there is no natural number whose successor is 0.
- P4: if K is a set such that: 0 is in K, and for every natural number n, n being in K implies that S(n) is in K; then K contains every natural number.

We had noticed that axiom O3 and P4 are all related with a kind of well foundedness, both can help us to setup the structure by induction. So let us define new structure Eq for equality

- Eq1: equality is reflexive, similar with P2.1
- Eq2: equality is symmetric, similar as P2.2
- Eq3: equality is transitive, similar as P2.3
- Eq4: Eq is closed under equality, similar as P2.4

and new structure Ind for inducible which are satisfied a serial of axioms

- Ind0: R is [well-founded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation)
- Ind1: we can construct Ind recursively by using R

Could we then define Cardinal number as Eq + Ind?

---

Thanks for comment from @coffeemath, I made revision to clarify inducible

Comment: What is Eq? Also what is meant by "inducible"? Just that P4 holds?

Comment: Thanks, @coffeemath . I am trying to use well-founded relation on equality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation , but did not reach a very clear conclusion. So I have to use a coined term which still need to be clarified.